# Can we sell 110V equipment without NRTL certification in a US market?

Tags: ac, power-electronics, certification, ul, equipment

- Only in some places.
- Weight scale product
- certification
- NRTL
- 110VAC

Answer (score 2):

There is no US federal law that requires it.  Your customer may require it for insurance or other reasons, or it might be required by city or state regulations.

Consider FCC and other regulations too..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can sell it. The NRTL is enforced at a local level and a legal liability (cover your butt). As far as the local enforcement goes, [OSHA requires](https://www.osha.gov/laws-regs/standardinterpretations/1993-08-24-0) product testing, so any organization that needs to be compliant theoretically could not use the product and be compliant with OSHA (and I'm no lawyer but I'm pretty sure that every businness in the US needs to be OSHA compliant).

> All electrical equipment, except those kinds which no NRTL accepts,
> certifies, lists, labels, or otherwise determines to be safe, must be
> "approved", as that term is defined at 29 CFR 1910.399. Except as
> indicated in the following this means that a NRTL must accept,
> certify, label, list, or otherwise determine that equipment is safe
> for it to be considered "approved".
>
> The requirement mandating that electrical equipment be "approved" is
> set forth at 29 CFR 1910.303(a). Also, OSHA Standard 29 CFR
> 1910.303(b)(2) requires that "approved" equipment be used in conformance with its approval.
> Source: [OSHA](https://www.osha.gov/laws-regs/standardinterpretations/1993-08-24-0)

As far as legal liablity, if your product causes a fire or electric shock and causes damage or loss of life, you could face legal ramifications. In addition to that a local fire marshal would also probably want the device thrown out if it didn't have an NRTL certification, this type of enforcement varies from region to region.

So if you were to sell the device (many of them) that are not prototypes, I would probably seek a NRTL certfication.

In addition to that you'll probably also want FCC certificaitons to prevent your device causes radio problems for other users,